# Positive correlation clustering

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have applied hierarchical clustering on the correlation matrix of my dataframe `df`
 as follows:

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch

X = df.corr().values
d = sch.distance.pdist(X) 
L = sch.linkage(d, method='complete')
C = sch.fcluster(L, 0.5*d.max(), 'distance')
```

How can I adjust this so that negative correlations are treated as 'bad'? What I am after is to cluster my variables based on how *positively* correlated they are. Hope the question makes sense :)

Comment: Why do you run `pdist` *on* `corr`?